# Transformation matrix - Are the matrices correct?

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to describe for the following $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces $V$with basis $B$ the matrix $A_{f, B, B}$ for $f\in \text{End}_K(V)$:

1. $V=\mathbb{R}^2, B=((1,0)^T, (0,1)^T)$ and $f$ the rotation by 45 degrees clockwise.
2. $V=\mathbb{C}, B=(1,i)$ and $f(z)=a^2\overline{z}$ with $a=\cos \alpha+i\sin\alpha, \alpha \in [0,2\pi)$.

$$$$

The matrix $A_{f, B, B}$ contains the coefficients $a_{ij}$ of $f(b_j)=\sum a_{ij}b_i$, right?

We have the following:

1. We have that $f(x)=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\frac{\pi}{4} & -\sin\frac{\pi}{4} \\ \sin\frac{\pi}{4} & \cos\frac{\pi}{4}\end{pmatrix}\cdot x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\cdot x$, right?

   Therefore we have the following:

   $$f(b_1)=f\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot b_1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot b_2 \\ f(b_2)=f\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot b_1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot b_2$$

   So, do we get $$A_{f, B, B}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}& -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{pmatrix}$$ ?
2. We have the following: $$f(1)=a^2=(\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha)^2=\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha-2i\cos\alpha\sin\alpha= (\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha)\cdot 1+(-2\cos\alpha\sin\alpha) \cdot i\\  f(i)=-a^2=-(\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha)^2=-\cos^2\alpha+\sin^2\alpha+2i\cos\alpha\sin\alpha=-(\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha)\cdot 1+(2\cos\alpha\sin\alpha) \cdot i$$

   So, do we get $$A_{f, B, B}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha& -(\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha)\\ -2\cos\alpha\sin\alpha&2\cos\alpha\sin\alpha\end{pmatrix}$$ ?

   How could we justify that $f$ is a reflection at the line $\{at: t\in \mathbb{R}\}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first, note that rotation matrix by $\theta$ clockwise is:
$$f(x)=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\ \theta & \sin\theta  \\ -\sin\theta  & \cos\theta \end{pmatrix}$$

Thus:

$$f(x)=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\frac{\pi}{4} & \sin\frac{\pi}{4} \\ -\sin\frac{\pi}{4} & \cos\frac{\pi}{4}\end{pmatrix}\cdot x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\cdot x$$

For the second we have:

$$a=\cos \alpha+i\sin\alpha\implies a^2= \cos^2 \alpha -\sin^2\alpha+2i\cos \alpha\sin \alpha $$

$$z=1\implies a^2 \bar z= a^2= \cos^2 \alpha -\sin^2\alpha+2i(\cos \alpha\sin \alpha)$$

$$z=i\implies a^2 \bar z= -ia^2= -i(\cos^2 \alpha -\sin^2\alpha)+2(\cos \alpha\sin \alpha) $$

Thus:

$$A_{f, B, B}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha&2(\cos\alpha\sin\alpha)\\ 2(\cos\alpha\sin\alpha)&-(\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha)\end{pmatrix}$$

To justify that $f$ is a reflection at the line $\{at: t\in \mathbb{R}\}$ note that:

$z\to f(z)=a^2 \bar z\to f(a^2 \bar z)=a^2 \bar a^2 z=z$

We can also verify this by matrix $A_{f, B, B}$, indeed:

$$A_{f, B, B}\cdot a=
\cos^3\alpha-\sin^2\alpha \cos\alpha+2(\cos\alpha\sin^2\alpha)+2i(\cos^2\alpha\sin\alpha)-i(\cos^2\alpha \sin \alpha-\sin^3\alpha)=
\cos^3\alpha+\sin^2\alpha\cos\alpha+i(\cos^2\alpha\sin\alpha+\sin^3\alpha)=\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha=a$$

Comment: Ah ok! So, we get \begin{equation*}A_{f, B, B}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*} right? The second transformation matrix is correct, or not? Do you have an idea about the second part, how we can justify that $f$ is a reflection at the line $\{at: t\in \mathbb{R}\}$ ?

Comment: I'm going to answer also for the seocnd, in his case the matrix should be a vector.

Comment: Why do we take at the second $f(z)$ and not $f(1)$ and $f(i)$ seperately?

Comment: you can also do by f(1) and f(i), the result should be the same!

Comment: oh sorry maybe I've mislead yhe second part! I revise.

Comment: I've revised, I think that in this case A is a vector. Of course you can define as a matrix in $\mathbb{R}^2$ but in this case you have $V=\mathbb{C}$

Comment: But do we not have to write f(1) and f(i) and a linear combination of the basis and then the coefficients are the matrix $A_{f, B,B}$ ?

Comment: Of course if you want express the final result as a vectoryou can put A in matrix form, I comlete the aswer with this!

Comment: I haven't really understoof why $f$ is not a reflection. Could you explain this further to me?

Comment: $\bar z$ is a reflection with respect to the x axis, but when you mupltiply by $a^2$ the resulting vector is elonged by $|a^2|$ and rotated by $\alpha$.

Comment: I've finally revised the answer for the second part. I was misleading the question, now A should work properly with respect to the basis (1,i)!

Comment: Ah ok! But at the question I have to justify why $f$ is a reflection at the line $\{at: t\in \mathbb{R}\}$. So, shouldn't it be a reflection? So that it is a reflection does it have to hold that $f^2(x)=x$, i.e. $f^2=id$ ?

Comment: ah ok sorry |a|=1 this it can be a reflection, yes f^2=id is a good check, you can also verify that $a$ is an eigenvector for $f$ with eigenvalue 1

Comment: I've added two final prove for the reflection also to check that A works.

Comment: Does $A_{f, B, B}\cdot a$ mean \begin{align*}A_{f, B, B}\cdot a&=\begin{pmatrix}\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha& 2\cos\alpha\sin\alpha\\ 2\cos\alpha\sin\alpha&-\cos^2 \alpha +\sin^2\alpha\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}\cos \alpha \\ \sin\alpha\end{pmatrix}\end{align*} ?

Comment: Yes exactly since $a=(\cos \alpha, \sin \alpha)$ in the base$ (1,i)$.

Comment: Ah ok! I got it!! Thank you!! :-)

Comment: @MaryStar You are welcome. I've made a little bit of confusion but at the end we have got a good result. Bye